# React-router - How to use multiple private routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My project have 2 different roles and both need login.

So I created 2 login pages and 2 private routes are `Auth` and `Trainee`

The problem is even I type an url is not children of `Auth` route it will go through `Auth` then it all wrong after that

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={LoginForAuthPath}
          component={LoginForAuthComponent}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={LoginForTraineePath}
          component={LoginForTraineeComponent}
        />
        <Auth>
          <Route
            exact
            path={SomeAuthPath}
            component={SomeAuthComponent}
          />
        </Auth>
        <Trainee>
          <Route
            exact
            path={SomeTraineePath}
            component={SomeTraineeComponent}
          />
        </Trainee>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

```
class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: isLoggedIn(),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loggedIn ? (
      <Route children={this.props.children} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={LoginPath} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Switch renders the first matching component/Route within its children.

Since Auth is rendered unconditionally and is a valid component, it stops matching after Auth is rendered and never reaches Trainee

You should perhaps change your implementation of Auth and Trainee so that they both use `Route` as the direct child

```
class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: isLoggedIn(),
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <Route {...rest} render={(rProps) => this.state.loggedIn? <Component {...rProps}/>: <Redirect to={LoginPath} />} /> 
  }
}
```

Similarly change the implementation of Trainee and use it like

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path={LoginForAuthPath}
      component={LoginForAuthComponent}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path={LoginForTraineePath}
      component={LoginForTraineeComponent}
    />
    <Auth
        exact
        path={SomeAuthPath}
        component={SomeAuthComponent}
    />
    <Trainee
        exact
        path={SomeTraineePath}
        component={SomeTraineeComponent}
      />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```